# How to generate a surface from other surfaces in Petrel

Tags: ocean, petrel

I have a task to create a new surface in Petrel. I am supposed to generate the average of two surfaces and create a new surface from it (like a mid surface) using Ocean for Petrel software.

Is this possible? and where do i start from? I would also appreciate links to resources that would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seslie,

You can create surface from Collection be calling method CreateRegularHeightFieldSurface(string name, SpatialLatticeInfo lattice);

To create property as RegularHeightFieldSurface.CreateProperty(Template template);

Then you can access to nodes of surface and property by I and J indexes. X and Y for surface will be generated automatically from lattice.

```
Point2[]  world = …
var surf = c.CreateRegularHeightFieldSurface(name, oldSurf.SpatialLattice, PetrelProject.PrimaryProject.CoordinateReferenceSystem));
SurfaceProperty prop = surf.CreateProperty(PetrelProject.WellKnownTemplates.PetrophysicalGroup.Pressure);
prop.Name = " Pressure ";
var sizeIj = surf.SpatialLattice.OriginalLattice.Arrays.SizeIJ;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeIj.I; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeIj.J; j++)
    {
        surf[i, j] = …;
        prop[i, j] = …;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the Ocean SDK, it comes with samples and documentation. The class you should use is RegularHeightFieldSurface - check in the Ocean.chm. There is a sample called PreStackSample which has an example on how to create such a surface.

Comment: Thankyou very much Thomas, for the swift and very useful response. I will get on it immediately