# Getting Surface Data in Ocean for Petrel

Tags: ocean, petrel

Is there a way to get the x, y and z point values of a particular surface in petrel through Ocean and print them out in the Petrel output window?

Comment: Hi Hallgrim, Surfaces in Petrel such as Base Cretaceous for example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to a RegularHeightFieldSurface, all the information you need is readily available in the Ocean SDK.  I believe you are looking for RegularHeightFieldSample.

The PetrelLogger can be used to output strings to the Message Log, log files or standard message boxes.

You asked an almost identical question here: [How to generate a surface from other surfaces in Petrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693002/how-to-generate-a-surface-from-other-surfaces-in-petrel).  Both current answers, that you acknowledged, also answers this question.

Ocean (like most moderately complex APIs) does require some upfront investment in getting acquainted with the basics. Stack Overflow is no substitute for self study.... :-)

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm not looking for a direct solution to my assignment, just a very good guide. I have infact being studying and trying to work on it on my own. The last question went a long way in helping me, I've been able to access the RegularHeightFieldSurface, create a new instance, get the names of the surfaces in the current project, create mine.. I just dont know if there's a way to print out the names of each points of the surfaces.. Not asking for the codes or anything like that. I would work on that with the help i get. Thanks

Comment: So, i felt really bad after i read your reply X_X and on the positive side, got challenged. Thanks for the hint (@RegularHeightFieldSample), I have been able to work on this, get points and display a new regular height field surface although not displaying the points in the info output window yet, but i'm sure i'll figure that out. :-)

Comment: Good - and I apologize for being a bit harsh!  I added a mention of the PetrelLogger class, which is the second part you're looking for.